# Issue sending data through pages in Next.js

Tags: routes, next.js

from my main page, I want, when clicking a button, to go to another page and transfer data to it, but it throws an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'users')". There are a lot of conflicting information about this on the Internet, so I thought it would be better to ask here. Here are the two components:

```
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Zeke´s Bill Splitter</h1>

        <h2>Enter the amount of people</h2>

        <form onSubmit={checkAmount}>
          <input 
          type="number"
          onChange={saveInput} />
          </form>

        <Link 
        href={{
          pathname: '/pages/mainPage',
          query: { users: users }
        }}>Go to main</Link>
      </>
    );
  };

  export default Page;
```

And this is the component that should recieve the data, but aparently it´s not recieving it:

```
  "use client"
  import React from 'react'
  import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"

  const MainPage = () => {

    const router = useRouter()
    const { userAmount } = router.query.users;

    return (
      <div>{userAmount}</div>
    )
  }

  export default MainPage
```

Does anybody have any idea? This is my first Next.js project and it's pretty confusing.

Comment: Try `query: { users: JSON.stringify(users) }`, and `const { userAmount } = JSON.parse(router.query.users);`. A query should be a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Next 13 we have two `useRouter`, one is exported from `'next/router'` that should be used with the old pages router and another exported from `'next/navigation'` that should be used with the new app router. The `router.query` property only exists in the router from `'next/router'`, since you are using the one from `'next/navigation'` (app folder implementation) `router.query` is returning as `undefined`. With the app router in order to get the query params you need to use `useSearchParams`. You can read more about it here https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params

```
"use client"
import React from 'react'
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';

const MainPage = () => {

  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const userAmount = searchParams.get('users');

  return (
    <div>{userAmount}</div>
  )
}

export default MainPage
```

Comment: that did it! thanks for clarifying it, I couldn´t find the right way to do it

Comment: Hi, I'm using Next 13 useRouter from next/navigation and I tried passing some data via router.push({pathname: '/event/code', query: {data: 'some data'}) but I get a path.startsWith is not a function error.
What I want to achieve is to pass some data from one page to another via router.push as I'm doing so via a function and not the Link component. 

I'd appreciate any guidance you can give.